# get distinct dates of timestamp elements in Basex with xquery

Tags: xquery, basex

I have the following xml format

```
<root>
    <node1>
        <timestamp>2016-05-16T00:57:30.889</timsetamp>  
    </node1>
    <node1>
        <timestamp>2016-05-18T00:57:30.889</timsetamp>  
    </node1>
    ....
</root>
```

how can I get the distinct dates(for example 2016-05-16,2016-05-18)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the dates, you can use XPath, casts and `fn:distinct-values()`:

```
distinct-values(//timestamp/xs:date(xs:dateTime(.)))
```